# Creating Dynamic Controllers in codeIgniter via CMS

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm currently building a CMS for a project in codeIgniter and I was wondering if there's any way to create dynamically a controller file in codeIgniter via the CMS when the user create a new page in the database. I don't need to create another model because the tables in the database will be the same, as well as the view. Basicly, all the page in the website (link, title, content etc.) are from the same table. I just want to keep the uri like this (www.mywebsite.com/class/function). Also no routing.

I was looking around the web and the only thing I found close of my request is the CRUD "codegen", but i can't use it online and there's alot of things I just don't need from it.

Comment: Why no routing?  If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, this is a perfect example of what routing would be used for.

Comment: The uri display just as I wanted and if I can do what I'm trying to do, I won't need to create a new routing for each pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to create a new controller each time the user adds a new page to the database, would it not be better to have a single controller which takes the db id or page name as parameter and loads that page?

So if the user created two pages called page1 and page2, and you have a controller that is used to serve all dynamic pages named dynamic.php then the urls would be

```
www.mysite.com/dynamic/page1
www.mysite.com/dynamic/page2
```

Creating a controller each time the user creates a page is a big overhead, and also would require lots of code to properly implement, like deleting the controller when the user deletes the page from database, for instance. And I think to provide a coding solution within SO would be cumbersome.

Comment: I finaly got it right and now, everything should be alot more simpler. `class Test extends CI_Controller {
 
    function fr($url, $sub_url="") {
        $em = $this->doctrine->em;
  if(empty($sub_url)){
   $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT page FROM models\Page page WHERE page.url = '".$url."'");
  }else if(!empty($sub_url)){
   $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT page FROM models\Page page WHERE page.url = '".$sub_url."'");
  }
  $result = $query->getResult();
        $data['pageContent'] = $result[0];
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }
}`

Comment: glad you got it figured out :)

Comment: @Sébastien Morin Barsalou: I also need the url as www.mysite.com/dynamic/page1 or page2. I have the controller dynamic. How to write the function. page1, page will be changed. How to call the static function for all page1, page2....